# An edible considered holy

Tags: phrase-request

If a holy man reads some verses, blows on something that we eat or drink such as water, can we say?

> Water with holy words read over.

OR

> Water with holy words recited on.

Answer (score 4):

You can try one of these:

- water over which holy words have been read
- water that has been blessed
- water upon which a holy man has breathed

Answer (score 0):

Try **Holy water**

> Holy water is water that has been blessed by a member of the clergy or a religious figure. [Holy Water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_water)

Answer (score 0):

*Consecrated* bread, water might serve if you're referring too Catholic tradition.

The term *sanctified* might also be useful.

J.R.'s answer here suggests *which has been blessed blessed* which is also good as well as *holy*. These are good, simple words.

I would advise caution with religious terminology as it's fairly easy to mix up claims of religious significance with claims of religious truth.